# TypeScript narrowed type

Tags: javascript, typescript, phpstorm

In my code, I've function like

```
public foo(inner: Partial<Inner>): void {
    let str = '';

    if (inner.text) {
      
      str += inner.text;
    }
  }
```

Inner is interface with many field like text: number;

In PhpStorm on the second inner.text, I've warning for narrowed type. But I doesn't know why and how to make for doesn't have a narrowed warning (except to disable option in inspection TypeScript)

Comment: what does `Partial<Inner>` look like?

Comment: `export interface Inner {
  text: number;
 date: Date;
finish: boolean;
}
`

Comment: I'm guessing its warning you that your are implicitly casting `.text` to a string when it should have been a number

Comment: I wish it was like that. But even if you put text: string, nothing changes

Comment: What _exactly_ is the error message you're seeing? Because the code you've posted so far seem to not have any errors: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSSSTTgG85UQYAuOJAVwFsAjNAbjgBNNVaARHsA7pkCAM4ALWswgQANsExIOAXwCwAKE3Y5mMWLgBBMprhww9ZnITY46WQApkxKLQAKmWAkxyAPIRcAPgBKWgA3CAROEw0zMwV4MRgoOABeOAByDLZNUziEdDgnIjQAOkoYYLI4szyapJSAanTnMoqc2Lj1Tu6VIA

Comment: phpstorm sets the background of the corresponding color to the following inspection 

Signals the use of a variable whose type is limited by a type protection. Note that the severity level does not affect this inspection.

Comment: I'm not sure what "warning" you're getting. But the `if` statement should narrow the type of `inner.text` from `number | undefined` to `number` - this is what you want, no?

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error/warning, the IDE just tells you that the type is [narrowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html); highlighting can be configured in **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | TypeScript, Variable type narrowed by a type guard**